# PLSQL Regexp expression

Tags: regex, plsql, character

I want to get values between = and ^ . My expression like;

```sql
select regexp_substr('NUMBER=2019-024^','\={1}([^^]+)',1, 1) from dual
```

I want only 2019-024 part. With these expression I got "=2019-024". How can I get 2019-024?

Thank you!

Comment: You can shorten it to `=([^^]+)` and take the group 1 value

Comment: It doesnt work. Still getting =2019-024

Answer (score 2):

I might even suggest *not* using regex here and instead resort to the base string functions:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, '=') + 1, INSTR(col, '^') - INSTR(col, '=') - 1)
FROM yourTable;
```

If you really want to use regex here, then use a capture group:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('NUMBER=2019-024^', '=(.*?)\^', 1, 1, NULL, 1) FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to escape the `\=` and you an omit `{1}`.

Add matching a `\^` (which does have to be escaped) at the end  to make sure that it is there.

The syntax for the capture group is:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('NUMBER=2019-024^', '=([^^]+)\^', 1, 1, NULL, 1) FROM dual;
```

Output

```
2019-024
```